# Left join returning no rows when no row from one of the joined tables is available

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user` 
LEFT JOIN `user_group` 
  ON `user_group`.`userid` = `user`.`userid` 
LEFT  JOIN `email_template` 
  ON `email_template`.`user_id`=`user`.`userid` 
WHERE `user`.`agent_id`='123' 
 AND `email_template`.`type`='advertise'
```

That is my sql statement. I am joining tables user, user group and email_template. The problem is for the user I am querying there is no email_template of type advertise in the table so the entire query returns no rows. Instead I want 1 row, with the email_template type column null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try moving the `email_template` filter to the join condition?

Doing this applies the filter on the join instead of the `WHERE` clause.  If you apply the filter on the `WHERE` then you are basically performing an `INNER JOIN` which will cause no rows to be returned if nothing meets the criteria:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user` 
LEFT JOIN `user_group` 
  ON `user_group`.`userid` = `user`.`userid` 
LEFT  JOIN `email_template` 
  ON `email_template`.`user_id`=`user`.`userid` 
  AND `email_template`.`type`='advertise'
WHERE `user`.`agent_id`='123'
```

Answer (score 2):

move the condition to select `email_templatetype='advertise'` on the time you are joining. Basically the `WHERE` clause causes the record to be filtered it does match on the condition.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `user` 
        LEFT JOIN `user_group` 
          ON `user_group`.`userid` = `user`.`userid` 
        LEFT  JOIN `email_template` 
          ON `email_template`.`user_id`=`user`.`userid` AND 
                `email_template`.`type`='advertise'
WHERE   `user`.`agent_id`='123'
```